# Force YouTube Playlist to HTML5 playback

Tags: css, youtube, html5-video

As I would like to be able to manipulate the z-index of an embedded Youtube playlist, I tried adding the html5 parameter, set to 1, but this seems to work for single video embedding only.

This works:

```
<iframe width="300" height="225" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?html5=1" frameborder="0">
```

But this doesn't:

```
<iframe width="300" height="225" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLAYLIST_ID&amp;html5=1" frameborder="0">
```

Many thanks :)

Comment: Maybe try it set src to `http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLAYLIST_ID&html5=1`

Comment: @Null: You mean changing the &amp; into &? Sadly, this doesnt work either..

Comment: YouTube is currently working the HTML5 Player. It is still in Beta and Playlists might not yet be supported.

Answer (score 1):

You are forcing the html 5 player the right way, youtube doesn't support this at the moment this will only work for single video's.

There are other solutions to have a html5 player play multiple youtube video's in html5.

Using mediaelement.js you can build something yourself (check which vid is playing, which one's next, if a video's finished, etc...). http://mediaelementjs.com/

After a quick Google I found a HTML5 player which actually has playlist support: http://mediafront.org/osmplayer/#.UK1L3eOe-pY